# Issues installing Mcrypt PHP module

Tags: macos, homebrew, php, versions

I am trying to install Mcrypt PHP module but encountering some issues:

- Version of PHP installed: 7.1.16
- macOS version: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Is the following command that I am running correct?

> Install the correct package, for me was 7.1.7 => homebrew/php/php71-mcrypt

`brew install homebrew/php/php71-mcrypt`

Answer (score 1):

The formula you are trying to install is deprecated. There was an [announcement](https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/) the 19 january 2018:

> By 31st March 2018 we will deprecate and archive the Homebrew/php tap. Unfortunately we have been unable to maintain an acceptable, consistent user or contributor experience and CI workload through non-core formula taps in the Homebrew organisation so we are continuing to migrate widely used formulae into Homebrew/core and encourage more niche formulae and options to be supported outside the Homebrew organisation.

Some of the PHP extensions are maintained by Kevin Abel in its [Github repository](https://github.com/kabel/homebrew-php-ext) but there is no mcrypt extension.

Moreover [mcrypt is itself deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php#migration71.deprecated.ext-mcrypt) and is considered as an abandonware for nearly a decade. It is removed from PHP 7.2. Read  this stackoverflow question for alternatives: [mcrypt is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)